# Coloring sets in plotly polar chart adds extra points?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I'm using plotly to make a scatter radar plot and I'm having issues when setting the colors in each set. Basically whenever I set the "color" parameter the plot shows extra points that are not in my original data.frame.

Small example:

```
df
        r                     t  my_sets
1  0.8090 108.00000000000000000 Set1
2  0.3090  -0.00000000000001029 Set3
3  0.8090  35.99999999999999289 Set1
4  0.5871 103.61382244080326132 Set2
5  0.6489 154.43699940042691310 Set2
6  0.3629 175.61382244080323289 Set3
```

If I do this:

```
p <- plot_ly(data=df, r=r, t=t, mode = "markers")
layout(p, title = "simple_test", plot_bgcolor = toRGB("grey90"))
```

[All 6 points are plotted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8kC7.png)

However when I do this:

```
p <- plot_ly(data=df, r=r, t=t, color = my_sets, mode = "markers")
layout(p, title = "simple_test", plot_bgcolor = toRGB("grey90"))
```

[I get 2 extra points with r>1 that are definitely not in my original df.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpXnt.png)

Any idea what the problem is? If I run the Hobbs example in the plotly website I dont seem to have this problem...

Comment: How do you do the assignment of the colors? The column `set` does not contain any valid color information, right? I would guess that the problem is there... Oh, and by the way: `set` might be an unfortunate name for a column / variable.

Comment: The thing is, the example in the plotly website doesn't explicitly set the colors so there is a default color selection to rely on. The color mapping in my example does work (even without explicitly selecting the colors), the issue are those extra points I'm not sure where they are coming from. I've tried setting specific colors also (`colors=c("red","blue","green")`) but the new points still show up. By the way, changed the name of the column to `my_set` to avoid confusion.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug that you should report on the Github page. When looking at the `plotly_build` object, the values look correct - there is no indication of those extra points. It's just when it renders. It looks like you need at least four points per category. When I modify your data to include 4 "Set1" and 4 "Set2" data points, it plots as expected.